# Looking for a way to add a column to an existing CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a script that imports a CSV document and I have a foreach statement that goes through and tests each object to check if it is within a specified range, returning true or false. I want the results of the foreach statement to be appended as a new columnn into the CSV document but I am struggling.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you are using, it will make providing a reasonable answer easier.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe `Import-Csv` to `Select-Object` and perform your test in a calculated property expression - in this example we're checking that the value of a column named `col` is between 0-10:

```
Import-Csv file.csv |
  Select-Object *,@{Name='TestResult';Expression={0 -le $_.col -and 10 -ge $_.col}} |
    Export-Csv modified.csv -NoTypeInformation
```